# VirtualBox - How to dynamic RAM allocation for Guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

VirtualBox Graphic User Interface Version 4.1.2_Ubuntu r38459 (installed with Ubuntu Software Center)

Host OS: Ubuntu 11.10
Guest OS: Windows XP sp 3 (with guest additions installed)

I have search on Google about this topic but not find any help yet. I read some topic that say VirtualBox v 4 now support dynamic RAM allocation but I do not know how to enable this feature.

Can you show me how to enable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature you are searching for is called Memory Ballooning: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-balloon

Comment: Can you describe how exactly? And does this make the guest OS have more memory for it's running applications?

Comment: As I understand it, running a VM that allows Memory Ballooning (requiring a setting and VirtualBox Guest Additions), a user can send a command to that VM to increase its memory allocation.

Note that this does not mean you can allocate 5 GB of memory to two VMs with only 8 GB of RAM (i.e. Memory Overcommitment). And the user must issue the command; it doesn't happen automatically, though I'm sure a clever user could configure performance polling scripts to query the VMs and issue the commands dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

like @Giovanni answered u will need to activate Memory Ballooning
however in the docs it is 
 ***--large-pages***
  which did not work for me! i needed to use 
**--largepages**

```
VBoxManage modifyvm machineName --largepages off
```